# When I click the button to review the quizz it stays in 0 but if you click it again it sum the score again and again each time you press it

Tags: javascript, html

```js
var data = document.getElementById("data");
var k = (0);
data.innerHTML = `
<h1 align = center> java .-. <h1>

`;


function verificar(){
   document.getElementById("az").innerHTML = "Calificacion:"+k
   var p1 = document.getElementById("p1").value;
   var p2 = document.getElementById("p2").value;
   var p3 = document.getElementById("p3").value;
   if (p1==7){   
      k++
   }  
   if (p2==184){   
      k++
   }  
   if (p3==125){   
      k++
   }  
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Java</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <H1 align=center>Pg de java </H1>
        <div id="data">        
        </div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label>√49</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="p1" id="p1">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label>92x2</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="p2" id="p2">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label>625/5</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="p3" id="p3">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="button" name="verificar" id="verificar" onclick="verificar()">                
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <font size = "3" id = "az">Calificacion:</font><font size = "3">/3</font>  
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <script src = "main.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Each time i press the button to review my quizz it shows a 0 but if you press it again it sum the k value each time you press it.
Its my first time using javascript.
K is a val that each time you have a correcto question k++.
Az is a text Id that lets the java code to change the text to: Calificación + k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that whenever you're clicking on the button, you're continuously updating the value of k without resetting it on every submits and you're printing its value even before checking the if statements.

Therefore, changes that you have to make is -

- include `k = 0` at the start of the `verificar()` function to locally reset the value.
- move `document.getElementById("az").innerHTML = "Calificacion:"+k` at the end of the if statements.

Your `verificar()` function should now look like this -

```js
function verificar(){
   k=0; 
   var p1 = document.getElementById("p1").value;
   var p2 = document.getElementById("p2").value;
   var p3 = document.getElementById("p3").value;
   if (p1==7){   
      k++
   }  
   if (p2==184){   
      k++
   }  
   if (p3==125){   
      k++
   }
   document.getElementById("az").innerHTML = "Calificacion:"+k 
}
```